# Flutter how to rotate image in basis of 5 star rating

Tags: flutter, dart

I am simply rotating my image but I don't get how I calculate the degree on basis of rating. I have on basis of 5 mean 4.5, 5,3 like this how I can rotate my image on behalf of these rating

My code

```
                                Positioned(
                                    left: width * 0.072,
                                    bottom: height * 0.067,
                                    child: RotationTransition(
                                      turns: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(
                                          180 / 360),
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                        'images/Needle.png',
                                        height: height * 0.02,
                                      ),
                                    )),
```

What i want to achieve is this

[image]

if the rating is 5 image needle will be near blue color. when it's 4 it will be near the green. Something like this. My image is rotating but I stuck on that calculation.

Answer (score 0):

As you have divided your whole rating system into 5 stars and you have a semicircle (180 degree and 3.14 radian) to represent it, you an divide that semi circle into 5 equal parts leading to 180/5 = 36 degree (0.62 radian) each part. So referring to that image it looks like your 0 degree is starting from right side, you can invert this logic. So  for :

```
1 star : 180 degree = 3.14 radian
2 stars : 180 - 36 = 144 degree = 2.51327 radian
3 stars : 144 - 36 = 108 degree = 1.88496 radian
4 stars : 108 - 36 = 72 degree = 1.25664 radian
5 stars : 72 - 36 = 36 degree = 0.628319 radian
```

Now using this calculation will lead the arrow to the end of every color mark (180 will will be on the end of red color, 144 will be on the end of yellow color etc.). If you want  to point the center of every color, you can subtract 18 degree from each.